# Existence of square root of 2

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking through Abbott's "Understanding Analysis" and would appreciate if someone could help me understand part of the motivation of his argument. I've gone through the entire proof and the thing that confuses me is when he is working with one of the two cases (say $\alpha^2<2$), he goes in a search for an element in $T$ that is ${\bf larger}$ than $\alpha$. Why did he choose larger? What is the relationship between having $\alpha^2<2$ relating to looking for a larger $\alpha$ as compared to $\alpha^2>2$ motivating a search for an element smaller than $\alpha$?

Here is the beginning of the proof:

Consider the set 
$$
T=\{t \in \mathbb{R}: t^2<2\}
$$
and set $\alpha =\sup T$. We prove $\alpha^2=2$ by ruling out the possibilities $\alpha^2<2$ and $\alpha^2>2$. 
Assume $\alpha^2<2$. Searching for an element of $T$ that is larger than $\alpha$, we write 
\begin{align*}
\left(\alpha + \frac{1}{n}\right)^2 = \alpha^2+ \frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2} \\
< \alpha^2+ \frac{2\alpha}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\\
=\alpha^2+\frac{2\alpha+1}{n} 
\end{align*}
and he goes on to show that larger element establishes a contradiction.

Thanks.

Comment: Because what would contradict $\alpha^2 < 2$ is finding an element of $T$ that is greater than $\alpha$; if such an element were found, it would prove that $\alpha$ was not in fact the supremum of $T$.  Finding an element of $T$ less than $\alpha$ would help us not at all to contradict $\alpha^2 < 2$.

Comment: Presumably, the proof then goes on to assume $\alpha^2 > 2$, and finds a number smaller than $\alpha$ that is nonetheless greater than any element of $T$, again contradicting our assumption that $\alpha$ was in fact the supremum.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.